# Is it able to justify fancychap?

Tags: chapters, justification, fncychap

Hi to many LaTeX experts! I am using fncychap (Bjornstrup). I would like to know if it is possible to align (justify) the title name inside of the square (explanatory photo attached. Since I have pretty long chapter title (3-4 lines), I want it to look better by align (justify) it. Is it doable? Could anyone please kindly teach me how to manipulate it?

[image]

A biiiiig thank in advance!

```
\usepackage[b5paper, right=25mm, left=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\begin{document}

\chapter{this is a loooooooong title, this is a test, this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. thisisatest. this is a test, thisisatest, this is a test, this is a longtitle}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a `minipage` of appropriate width inside the chapter command:

[image: minipage]

Depending on the effect you want, you may have to adjust the width, and/or use manual line breaks to adjust for any hyphenating.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[b5paper, right=25mm, left=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=35mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\begin{document}


\chapter{\begin{minipage}{4in}this is a loooooooong title, this is a test, this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. thisisatest. this is a test, thisisatest, this is a test, this is a longtitle\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

justifying would look bad at such a large font size. You would get too large word spaces, and hyphenation in a chapter title looks normally odd too. The best is to manually split the lines so that if fits the meaning and gives a good looking result.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[b5paper, right=25mm, left=25mm, top=30mm, bottom=35mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}

\begin{document}

\chapter[text for the table of contents]
{this is a loooooooong title, this is a test, \\
 this is a test. this is a test. this is a test. \\ 
 this is a test. thisisatest. this is a test,\\ 
 thisisatest, this is a test, this is a longtitle!}

\end{document}
```

[image]